I can't set up routes for some pages in laravel 10
I can't set up the routes for certain pages in Laravel 10 since I can't get a view of my pages.
When I launch the timetable page it shows me an error like : 404
Not Found
Here is my menu in the sidebar that I set up for the schedule :
 <li class="nav-item nav-item-submenu {{ in_array(Route::currentRouteName(), ['tt.index', 'ttr.edit', 'ttr.show', 'ttr.manage']) ? 'nav-item-expanded nav-item-open' : '' }} ">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="icon-graduation2"></i> <span> Activité Académique</span></a>

                <ul class="nav nav-group-sub" data-submenu-title="Manage Academics">

                {{--Timetables--}}
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ route('tt.index') }}" class="nav-link {{ in_array(Route::currentRouteName(), ['tt.index']) ? 'active' : '' }}">Emplois du Temps</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <!-- Note -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="nc-icon nc-notes"></i>
                    <span class="no-icon">Evaluation & Bulletin</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.evaluation.index') }}">Evaluation</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.report.index') }}">Bulletin</a>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Bilan -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="nc-icon nc-paper-2"></i>
                    <span class="no-icon">Bilan périodique</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.bilan.appreciation') }}">Appréciation</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.bilan.grade') }}">Notes</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.bilan.confirmation') }}">Confirmation note &
                        appré</a>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                </div>
            </li>

``

Here is my ClassTimatable controller that I made for the schedule:

class ClassTimetableController extends Controller
{
protected $tt, $classroom_id, $evaluation, $year, $tt_records;

public function __construct(TimeTableRepo $tt, MyClassRepo $classroom,  EvaluationRepo $evaluation)
 {
//     $this->tt = $tt;
//     $this->classroom = $classroom;
//     // $this->evaluation = $evaluation;
//     $this->tt_records = $tt;


}
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $yearID = $request->input('year');
    $periodID = $request->input('period');
    $classroom = Classroom::find($request->input('classroom'));
    $matterID = $request->input('matter');
    $evaluationID = $request->input('evaluation');
    $datas = [];

    $year = Year::find($yearID);
    $period = Period::find($periodID);
    $matter = Matter::find($matterID);
    $evaluation = Evaluation::find($evaluationID);

    $years = Year::all();
    $matters = Matter::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

    $classrooms = Classroom::all();
    $evaluations = Evaluation::all();
    $tt_records = TimeTableRecord::all();
    //$tt_records = $this->tt->getAllRecords();


return view('admin.class_timetable.index', compact('year', 'period', 'classrooms', 'matter', 'datas', 'evaluations', ));

}


public function manage($ttr_id)
{
    $d['ttr_id'] = $ttr_id;
    $d['ttr'] = $ttr = $this->tt->findRecord($ttr_id);
    $d['time_slots'] = $this->tt->getTimeSlotByTTR($ttr_id);
    $d['ts_existing'] = $this->tt->getExistingTS($ttr_id);
    $d['matters'] = $this->classroom->getMatter(['classroom_id' => $ttr->classroom_id])->get();
    $d['classroom'] = $this->classroom->find($ttr->classroom_id);

    if($ttr->evaluation_id){
        $d['evaluation_id'] = $ttr->evaluation_id;
        $d['evaluation'] = $this->evaluation->find($ttr->evaluation_id);
    }

    $d['tts'] = $this->tt->getClassTimeTable(['ttr_id' => $ttr_id]);

    return view('admin.class_timetable.manage',compact('datas', $d));
}



public function store(TTRequest $req)
{
    $data = $req->all();
    $tms = $this->tt->findTimeSlot($req->ts_id);
    $d_date = $req->evaluation_date ?? $req->day;
    $data['timestamp_from'] = strtotime($d_date.' '.$tms->time_from);
    $data['timestamp_to'] = strtotime($d_date.' '.$tms->time_to);

    $this->tt->create($data);

    return Qs::jsonStoreOk();
}

public function update(TTRequest $req, $tt_id)
{
    $data = $req->all();
    $tms = $this->tt->findTimeSlot($req->ts_id);
    $d_date = $req->evaluation_date ?? $req->day;
    $data['timestamp_from'] = strtotime($d_date.' '.$tms->time_from);
    $data['timestamp_to'] = strtotime($d_date.' '.$tms->time_to);

    $this->tt->update($tt_id, $data);

    return back()->with('flash_success', __('msg.update_ok'));

}

public function delete($tt_id)
{
    $this->tt->delete($tt_id);
    return back()->with('flash_success', __('msg.delete_ok'));
}

/*********** TIME SLOTS *************/

public function store_time_slot(TSRequest $req)
{
    $data = $req->all();
    $data['time_from'] = $tf =$req->hour_from.':'.$req->min_from;
    $data['time_to'] = $tt = $req->hour_to.':'.$req->min_to;
    $data['timestamp_from'] = strtotime($tf);
    $data['timestamp_to'] = strtotime($tt);
    $data['full'] = $tf.' - '.$tt;

    if($tf == $tt){
        return response()->json(['msg' => __('msg.invalid_time_slot'), 'ok' => FALSE]);
    }

    $this->tt->createTimeSlot($data);
    return Qs::jsonStoreOk();
}

public function use_time_slot(Request $req, $ttr_id)
{
    $this->validate($req, ['ttr_id' => 'required'], [], ['ttr_id' => 'TimeTable Record']);

    $d = [];  //  Empty Current Time Slot Before Adding New
    $this->tt->deleteTimeSlots(['ttr_id' => $ttr_id]);
    $time_slots = $this->tt->getTimeSlotByTTR($req->ttr_id)->toArray();

    foreach($time_slots as $ts){
        $ts['ttr_id'] = $ttr_id;
        $this->tt->createTimeSlot($ts);
    }

    return redirect()->route('ttr.manage', $ttr_id)->with('flash_success', __('msg.update_ok'));

}

public function edit_time_slot($ts_id)
{
    $d['tms'] = $this->tt->findTimeSlot($ts_id);
    return view('ad in.class_timetable.time_slots.edit',compact('datas', $d));
}

public function update_time_slot(TSRequest $req, $ts_id)
{
    $data = $req->all();
    $data['time_from'] = $tf =$req->hour_from.':'.$req->min_from;
    $data['time_to'] = $tt = $req->hour_to.':'.$req->min_to;
    $data['timestamp_from'] = strtotime($tf);
    $data['timestamp_to'] = strtotime($tt);
    $data['full'] = $tf.' - '.$tt;

    if($tf == $tt){
        return back()->with('flash_danger', __('msg.invalid_time_slot'));
    }

    $this->tt->updateTimeSlot($ts_id, $data);
    return redirect()->route('ttr.manage', $req->ttr_id)->with('flash_success', __('msg.update_ok'));
}

public function delete_time_slot($ts_id)
{
    $this->tt->deleteTimeSlot($ts_id);
    return back()->with('flash_success', __('msg.delete_ok'));
}


/*********** RECORDS *************/

public function edit_record($ttr_id)
{
    $d['ttr'] = $ttr = $this->tt->findRecord($ttr_id);
    $d['evaluations'] = $this->evaluation->getEvaluation(['year' => $ttr->year, 'period' => $ttr->period]);
    //$d['classrooms'] = $this->classroom->all();
    $classrooms = Classroom::all();

    return view('admin.class_timetable.edit', compact('year', 'period', 'classrooms', 'matter', 'datas', 'evaluations', $d ));
}

public function show_record($ttr_id)
{
    $d_time = [];
    $d['ttr'] = $ttr = $this->tt->findRecord($ttr_id);
    $d['ttr_id'] = $ttr_id;
    $d['classroom'] = $this->classroom->find($ttr->classroom_id);

    $d['time_slots'] = $tms = $this->tt->getTimeSlotByTTR($ttr_id);
    $d['tts'] = $tts = $this->tt->getTimeTable(['ttr_id' => $ttr_id]);

    if($ttr->evaluation_id){
        $d['evaluation_id'] = $ttr->evaluation_id;
        $d['evaluation'] = $this->evaluation->find($ttr->evaluation_id);
        $d['days'] = $days = $tts->unique('evaluation_date')->pluck('evaluation_date');
        $d_date = 'evaluation_date';
    }

    else{
        $d['days'] = $days = $tts->unique('day')->pluck('day');
        $d_date = 'day';
    }

    foreach ($days as $day) {
        foreach ($tms as $tm) {
            $d_time[] = ['day' => $day, 'time' => $tm->full, 'matter' => $tts->where('ts_id', $tm->id)->where($d_date, $day)->first()->matter->name ?? NULL ];
        }
    }

    $d['d_time'] = collect($d_time);

    return view('admin.class_timetable.show', compact('datas', $d));
}
public function print_record($ttr_id)
{
    $d_time = [];
    $d['ttr'] = $ttr = $this->tt->findRecord($ttr_id);
    $d['ttr_id'] = $ttr_id;
    $d['classroom'] = $this->classroom->find($ttr->lassroom_id);

    $d['time_slots'] = $tms = $this->tt->getTimeSlotByTTR($ttr_id);
    $d['tts'] = $tts = $this->tt->getTimeTable(['ttr_id' => $ttr_id]);

    if($ttr->evaluation_id){
        $d['evaluation_id'] = $ttr->evaluation_id;
        $d['evaluation'] = $this->evaluation->find($ttr->evaluation_id);
        $d['days'] = $days = $tts->unique('evaluation_date')->pluck('evaluation_date');
        $d_date = 'evaluation_date';
    }

    else{
        $d['days'] = $days = $tts->unique('day')->pluck('day');
        $d_date = 'day';
    }

    foreach ($days as $day) {
        foreach ($tms as $tm) {
            $d_time[] = ['day' => $day, 'time' => $tm->full, 'matter' => $tts->where('ts_id', $tm->id)->where($d_date, $day)->first()->matter->name ?? NULL ];
        }
    }

    // $d['d_time'] = collect($d_time);
    // $d['s'] = Setting::all()->flatMap(function($s){
    //     return [$s->type => $s->description];
    // });

    return view('admin.class_timetable.print', compact('data', $d));
}

public function store_record(TTRecordRequest $req)
{
    $data = $req->all();
    $data['year'] = $this->year;
    $this->tt->createRecord($data);

    return Qs::jsonStoreOk();
}

public function update_record(TTRecordRequest $req, $id)
{
    $data = $req->all();
    $this->tt->updateRecord($id, $data);

    return Qs::jsonUpdateOk();
}

public function delete_record($ttr_id)
{
    $this->tt->deleteRecord($ttr_id);
    return back()->with('flash_success', __('msg.delete_ok'));
}

}

My route:

##############################mTimetable##############################################
Route::prefix('class_timetable')->name('class_timetable.')->controller(ClassTimetableController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index')->name('index');


    Route::post('/', 'store')->name('tt.store');
    Route::put('/{tt}', 'update')->name('tt.update');
    Route::delete('/{tt}', 'delete')->name('tt.delete');


    /*************** TimeTable Records *****************/


    Route::prefix('records')->name('records.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('manage/{ttr}', 'manage')->name('ttr.manage');
        Route::post('/', 'store_record')->name('ttr.store');
        Route::get('edit/{ttr}', 'edit_record')->name('ttr.edit');
        Route::put('/{ttr}', 'update_record')->name('ttr.update');


        Route::get('show/{ttr}', 'show_record')->name('ttr.show');
        Route::get('print/{ttr}', 'print_record')->name('ttr.print');
        Route::delete('/{ttr}', 'delete_record')->name('ttr.destroy');
    });

    /*************** Time Slots *****************/

    Route::prefix('time_slots')->name('time_slots.')->group (function () {
        Route::post('/', 'store_time_slot')->name('ts.store');
        Route::post('/use/{ttr}', 'use_time_slot')->name('ts.use');
        Route::get('edit/{ts}', 'edit_time_slot')->name('ts.edit');
        Route::delete('/{ts}', 'delete_time_slot')->name('ts.destroy');
        Route::put('/{ts}', 'update_time_slot')->name('ts.update');
    });

});

My view:
 <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header header-elements-inline">
        <h6 class="card-title">Gestion des Emplois du Temps</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-highlight">

            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#add-tt" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Créer un Emploi du Temps</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Afficher Emplois du Temps</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    @foreach ($classrooms as $classroom)
                        <a href="#ttr{{ $classroom->id }}" class="dropdown-item"
                            data-toggle="tab">{{ $classroom->name }}</a>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="add-tt">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form class="ajax-store" method="post" action="{{ url('ttr.store') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label font-weight-semibold">Nom <span
                                    class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <input name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required type="text"
                                    class="form-control" placeholder="Nom de l'emploi du temps">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="classroom_id" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label font-weight-semibold">Salle de
                                classe <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <select required data-placeholder="Select Classroom" class="form-control select"
                                    name="classroom_id" id="classroom_id">
                                    @foreach ($classrooms as $classroom)
                                        <option {{ old('classroom_id') == $classroom->id ? 'selected' : '' }}
                                            value="{{ $classroom->id }}">{{ $classroom->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="evaluation_id" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label font-weight-semibold">Type (Classe
                                ou Evaluation)</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <select class="select form-control" name="evaluation_id" id="evaluation_id">
                                    <option value="">Emploi du Temps de la Classe</option>
                                    @foreach ($evaluations as $evaluation)
                                        <option {{ old('evaluation_id') == $evaluation->id ? 'selected' : '' }}
                                            value="{{ $evaluation->id }}">{{ $evaluation->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <button id="ajax-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Soumettre <i
                                    class="icon-paperplane ml-2"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            @foreach ($classrooms as $classroom)
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ttr{{ $classroom->id }}">
                    <table class="table datatable-button-html5-columns">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>S/N</th>
                                <th>Nom</th>
                                <th>Classe</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Année</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if (isset($tt_records))
                                @foreach ($tt_records->where('classroom_id', $classroom->id) as $ttr)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $ttr->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $ttr->classroom->name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $ttr->evaluation_id ? $ttr->evaluation->name : 'Class TimeTable' }}
                                        <td>{{ $ttr->year }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            <div class="list-icons">
                                                <div class="dropdown">
                                                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                        <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                                                    </a>

                                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                                        {{-- View --}}
                                                        <a href="{{ route('ttr.show', $ttr->id) }}"
                                                            class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-eye"></i> Afficher</a>
                                                        {{-- Manage --}}
                                                        <a href="{{ route('ttr.manage', $ttr->id) }}"
                                                            class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-plus-circle2"></i>
                                                            Gestion</a>
                                                        {{-- Edit --}}
                                                        <a href="{{ route('ttr.edit', $ttr->id) }}"
                                                            class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                                                            Modifier</a>
                                                        {{-- Delete --}}
                                                  <a id="{{ $ttr->id }}" onclick="confirmDelete(this.id)"
                                                            href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i
                                                                class="icon-trash"></i>
                                                            Supprimer</a>
                                                        <form method="post" id="item-delete-{{ $ttr->id }}"
                                                            action="{{ route('ttr.destroy', $ttr->id) }}"
                                                            class="hidden">
                                                            @csrf @method('delete')                                                           </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{{-- TimeTable Ends --}}

@endsection
`
The capture:enter image description here

what URL are you trying to reach that gives you the 404? and is it a Laravel 404 or a webserver 404?

Route::post('/', 'store_record')->name('ttr.store');

Take a look at what the error in storage/logs is. The 404 error have many reasons

what URL, not what route

Make sure your route file is included in routes/web.php, if that is already the case, give your RouteServiceProvider file a visit, specifically the map() and mapWebRoutes() functions that define the routes for the application, consider sharing that too if the probleme persists.
